# jQuery infinite scroll causes links to temporarily not work?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, infinite-scroll

A couple of weeks ago I implemented an infinite scrolling page with jquery. The scrolling itself works great, but I'm getting a very strange side effect.

When I scroll and the new content loads, none of the links work for the first few seconds. In fact, no links anywhere on the page work for a couple of seconds. And it seems to get worse if I scroll really really far, for instance loading 5 pages in quick succession - then I'll have to wait 20 seconds before any of the links anywhere on the page are clickable.

I'm having the same experience using Firefox or IE8, so I'm guessing it's not the browser.

Any ideas what the cause or fix is?

Answer (score 0):

Still have this problem?

**Questions:**

- After 20 seconds once the page loads are the links clickable? Is the browser "frozen" for 20 seconds or is it just the links that arn't clickable?
- To load more content is it a link that says "show more" or is the content automatically loaded once the user hits the bottom of the page?
- Are you using jQuery's .scroll() to update the content?

**Initial Thoughts:**

- Are you using .click() or .bind('click', *function*) for the links that arn't clickable? Try .live('click', *function*) instead.
- Try using a setTimeout. For some browser jQuery's .scroll calls the handler function every pixel the scrollbar is changed... not once all the scrolling is done which can cause an overload of function call. Try something like this do that it doesn't do 1000 function calls when you scroll (this is just a quick example... code could be better):

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var scrolling = false;
      $(document).scroll('setScroll');

      function setScroll() {
          scrolling = setTimeout(doScrollUpdate, 300);
      }

      function doScrollUpdate() {
          clearTimeout(scrolling);
          // Do your ajax stuff here
      }
  </script>
  ```